# How to flatten nested arrays of objects into an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I convert this complex array:

```
[
  [
    { nums: [2,2] },
    { nums: [2,3] },
    { nums: [2,6] }

  ],
  [
    { nums: [3,2] },
    { nums: [3,4] },
    { nums: [3,5] },
    { nums: [3,9] }

  ],
  [  
    { nums: [4,2] },
    { nums: [4,3] },
  ]
]
```

Into this simplified version?:

```
  [
    [2,2],
    [2,3],
    [2,6],
    [3,2],
    [3,4],
    [3,5],
    [3,9],
    [4,2],
    [4,3]
  ]
```

Comment: define *"best"'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the array and then [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map the objects to only their `nums` field like so:

```js
let data = [
  [
    { nums: [2,2] },
    { nums: [2,3] },
    { nums: [2,6] }

  ],
  [
    { nums: [3,2] },
    { nums: [3,4] },
    { nums: [3,5] },
    { nums: [3,9] }

  ],
  [  
    { nums: [4,2] },
    { nums: [4,3] },
  ]
];

console.log(data.flat().map(obj => obj.nums));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert them using the following line of codes:

```
let finalArray =[];
array.forEach((element)=>{
element.forEach((innerElement)=>{
    finalArray.push(innerElement.nums)
   }  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `flatMap` to flatten the data:

```js
var array=[
  [
    { nums: [2,2] },
    { nums: [2,3] },
    { nums: [2,6] }

  ],
  [
    { nums: [3,2] },
    { nums: [3,4] },
    { nums: [3,5] },
    { nums: [3,9] }

  ],
  [  
    { nums: [4,2] },
    { nums: [4,3] },
  ]
];

var result = array.flatMap(e=>e.map(p=>p.nums));

console.log(result);
```